# проблема при десериализации пустого элемента xml

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

есть простой хмл

```
<doc> 
  <Dep>
    <Dprtm_code></Dprtm_code> 
    <Dprtm_name></Dprtm_name>
  </Dep>
</doc>
```

проблема в том что Dprtm_code может быть как заполнен `<Dprtm_code>234234234</Dprtm_code>` так и нет `<Dprtm_code></Dprtm_code>`. создал схему :

```
//...
<xs:element type="xs:long" name="Dprtm_code" nillable="true"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Dprtm_name"/>
//...
```

создал класс и в нем описал эти поля:

```
//...
private long? dprtm_codeField;    
private string dprtm_nameField;

[XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
public long? Dprtm_code {
    get {
        return this.dprtm_codeField;
    }
    set {
        this.dprtm_codeField = value;
    }
}
public string Dprtm_name {
    get {
        return this.dprtm_nameField;
    }
    set {
        this.dprtm_nameField = value;
    }
}
//...
```

но при десериализации хмл с пустым кодом `<Dprtm_code></Dprtm_code>` падает ошибка приведения типов. собственно вопрос: как правильно объявить елементы которые могут быть пустыми в xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xml, соответствующий приведённой схеме и десериализующийся в приведённый класс, должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Dep>
    <Dprtm_code xsi:nil="true"></Dprtm_code>
    <Dprtm_name></Dprtm_name>
  </Dep>
</doc>
```

То есть, обязательно должен быть атрибут `nil` из указанного пространства имён. Его корректно обрабатывает `XmlSerializer` (полагаю, что используется именно он).

При сериализации атрибут `xsi:nil` будет добавляться автоматически при необходимости.

Без этого атрибута валидация по схеме тоже не проходит.